# How to have Vue/Vuetify Autocomplete filter on two properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

## Background

So I have a vuetify autocomplete input that I'm using to search a table of parts. The parts table has an identity column, part number column, revision column, description column and a few other columns of information.

I have it working so the autocomplete options show the part number, rev and descriptions while typing in the text field filters the parts by part number.

[image: Current Version pic 1]

## Problem

But my goal is to be able to filter on both the part number and the description.

I've tried modifying **item-text="fpartno"** but cannot figure out how to have it work with two or more properties. And most solutions I've found online only affect how the options are displayed not how they are filtered.

Also removing **item-text** doesn't work either.

[image: Current Version pic 2]

## Code

I put my autocomplete into Single Page Component. I am currently using Typescript but I will also accept an answer that uses javascript. If I can just use the template syntax that would be ideal.

**Note:** the property *fcomment* contains the description in case anyone was confused.

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid grid-list-xl>
        <v-layout wrap align-center>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex>
                <v-autocomplete :items="inmastxs"
                                label="Part #"
                                item-value="identity_column"
                                item-text="fpartno"
                                cache-items
                                :search-input.sync="search"
                                solo>
                    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
                        {{ data.item.fpartno }} - {{ data.item.frev }} ({{ data.item.fcomment }})
                    </template>
                    <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
                        {{ data.item.fpartno }} - {{ data.item.frev }} ({{ data.item.fcomment }})
                    </template>

                </v-autocomplete>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

    import Vue from 'vue'
    import { Component, Prop, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    import { inmastx } from '../../models/M2M/inmastx';
    import axios from 'axios';

    @Component({})
    export default class InMastxSearch extends Vue {
        private search: string = "";
        private PartNumber: string = "";
        private loading: boolean = false;
        private inmastxs: inmastx[] = [];

        @Watch('search')
        onPropertyChanged(value: string, oldValue: string) {
            this.fetchParts(value);
        }


        private mounted() {
            this.fetchParts("");
        }

        private fetchParts(value: string) {
            if (value == null) {
                value = "";
            }

            console.log(value);
            this.loading = true
            axios.get("../odata/inmastx?$orderby=fpartno,frev&$top=10&$filter=contains(fpartno,'" + value + "') or contains(fcomment,'" + value + "')")
                .then((response) => {
                    this.inmastxs = response.data.value;
                    console.log(this.inmastxs);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }).then(() => {
                    this.loading = false;
                });
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you need anymore details let me know, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Late to the game here but the solution is to bind a custom filter

```
<v-autocomplete
  :filter="filterObject"
>
```

and then define the behavior

```
  methods: {
    filterObject(item, queryText, itemText) {
      return (
        item.prop1.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(queryText.toLocaleLowerCase()) >
          -1 ||
        item.prop2.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(queryText.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1
      );
    }
  }
```

The [v-autocomplete filter prop documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes) provides a link to the [default ts implementation](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VAutocomplete/VAutocomplete.ts#L36).

Comment: while I applying the method its throwing the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLocaleLowerCase' of undefined`.

Comment: Check that your "item" in this example contains defined properties (e.g. `{ prop1: "hello", prop2: "world" }`) and that the queryText is a string.

Answer (score 8):

Take away:

```
item-text="fpartno"
```

and use:

```
no-filter="true"
```

Comment: no filter is the way to go if your response have different props that you wanna select from.

Answer (score 5):

So I realized I was using the wrong tool for the job. While reading the docs I must have missed the section regarding the Combobox which has everything I need.

Anyways, changing **v-autocomplete** to **v-combobox** removing **item-text="fpartno"** and adding a custom filter gave my component the functionality I needed.

Here it is working correctly:

[image: Fixed pic 1]

Below is my updated code:

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid grid-list-xl>
        <v-layout wrap align-center>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex>
                <v-combobox :items="inmastxs"
                                label="Part #"
                                item-value="identity_column"
                                :filter="PartRevDescFilter"
                                cache-items
                                :search-input.sync="search"
                                solo>
                    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
                        {{ data.item.fpartno }} - {{ data.item.frev }} ({{ data.item.fcomment }})
                    </template>
                    <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
                        {{ data.item.fpartno }} - {{ data.item.frev }} ({{ data.item.fcomment }})
                    </template>    
                </v-combobox>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

    import Vue from 'vue'
    import { Component, Prop, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    import { inmastx } from '../../models/M2M/inmastx';
    import axios from 'axios';

    @Component({})
    export default class InMastxSearch extends Vue {
        private search: string = "";
        private PartNumber: string = "";
        private loading: boolean = false;
        private inmastxs: inmastx[] = [];

        @Watch('search')
        onPropertyChanged(value: string, oldValue: string) {
            this.fetchParts(value);
        }    

        private mounted() {
            this.fetchParts("");
        }

        private fetchParts(value: string) {
            if (value == null) {
                value = "";
            }
            this.loading = true
            axios.get("../odata/inmastx?$orderby=fpartno,frev&$top=10&$filter=contains(fpartno,'" + value + "') or contains(fcomment,'" + value + "')")
                .then((response) => {
                    this.inmastxs = response.data.value;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }).then(() => {
                    this.loading = false;
                });
        }

        private PartRevDescFilter(item: inmastx, queryText, itemText) {         
            return (item.fpartno.toLowerCase().includes(queryText.toLowerCase()) || item.frev.toLowerCase().includes(queryText.toLowerCase()) || item.fcomment.toLowerCase().includes(queryText.toLowerCase()));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Because the title of the question mentions Autocomplete not combobox I don't think that this answer is enough to be considered the best answer. Unless Autocomplete was the wrong tool all along.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Vuetify 3 Beta version which `filter` prop name is changed to `custom-filter`.

```
:custom-filter="customFilter"
```