# Vuetify search in v-autocomplete with property item-text or another property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've a *Todo list* which is *an array of objects* with properities (`id, title, description`) Also I want to display *`title`* in *`v-autocomplete`* but when I do search for word it's fine, but what I want is Doing search for *`description`* or *`title`*.
For Example: if I type *programming*, it will display to me *Read books*.

**Template**

```html
 <v-autocomplete
    v-model="idTodo"
    :items="todos"
    label="search todo..."
    item-value="id"
    item-text="title"
  />
```

**Script**

```js
    visitCategories: [],
    todos: [
      { id: 1, title: "Read books", description: "read books related to programming" },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "watch tutorials",
        description: "watch tutorials in many platforms like Youtube, Udemy...",
      },
    ],
    idTodo: -1,
```

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54561935

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have Vue/Vuetify Autocomplete filter on two properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54561935/how-to-have-vue-vuetify-autocomplete-filter-on-two-properties)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is to bind a custom filter.

```
    <v-autocomplete
    v-model="idTodo"
    :items="todos"
    label="search todo..."
    :filter="filterData"
    item-value="id"
  />
```

And then define the 'filterData' function in methods properties.

```
    methods: {
    filterData(item, queryText) {
      return (
        item.title.toLowerCase().includes(queryText.toLowerCase()) ||  
        item.description.toLowerCase().includes(queryText.toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  }
```